# Connecting to AS400/iSeries using Oracle WebLogic Server

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic, ibm-midrange

I have encountered a problem when setting up a Data Source in Oracle WebLogic Server that is an AS400. When setting it up and testing the connection I get the error message:

***"The application requester cannot establish the connection"***

When checking on IBMs website I found the following:

> What does "The application requester cannot establish the connection"
>   mean?
>
> The Toolbox JDBC driver uses the system name, user ID, and password
>   provided in the call to DriverManager.getConnection() to establish a
>   connection to the IBM i database. If any of these are not provided,
>   the Toolbox JDBC driver will display a sign-on prompt. If the Toolbox
>   JDBC driver can not sign on to the system for any reason, it will
>   throw an SQLException with the message "The application requester
>   cannot establish the connection". Here is a list of potential causes
>   for this exception: The system name is incorrect. One way to verify
>   this is to use ping with the specified system name. If ping fails,
>   then there is a TCP/IP configuration problem between your client and
>   the system. The user ID or password is incorrect. The IBM i database
>   host server is not started. You can start this by running STRHOSTSVR
>   *DATABASE on the IBM i command line. You can verify if the IBM i database host server is running 
>   using the utilities.JPing application.

(http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/faq/jdbc.html#faqC6)

When I ping the server, it fails - which also makes sense. However, when I use just a plain java file that opens a connection, fires an sql and closes the connection like

```
connection1 = DriverManager.getConnection("server", "user", "password")
Statement statement1 = connection1.createStatement();
ResultSet result1 = statement1.executeQuery("SQLquery")
```

i get a perfect connection and correct result. How is this possible? How can I connect via WebLogic and ODI?

PS: I already installed the AS400 driver according to this [manual](http://appliedintegration.blogspot.de/2010_10_01_archive.html)

Comment: Are you sure the WebLogic JDBC connection is trying to reach the same server, port and service name, and with the same credentials, as your plain Java version?

Comment: it is exactly the same. the web logic, however requests me to name a port (which i double checked it is open) additional to the IP, while in the java file i just named the servers IP.

Comment: Adding what you actually entered might help. What port number did you give WebLogic? Is it actually the Oracle listener port on that server? If it's an Oracle driver then `getConnection` probably defaults to 1521, but I've only seen that used with a URL (including the port usually) so I'm a little confused.

Comment: What do you mean by "(which i double checked it is open)"? That is, how did you check? (And what port was it?)

Comment: the server administrator confirmed multiple times that the port is open. Is there a way to check which port is open? it is the port 8474. i will try using 1521.

Comment: I am not using the oracle driver. both times i am using the IBM toolkit JDBC driver. it is called "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"

Comment: Doesnt seem to be a drive issue - you would have got a different error otherwise. This seems to me to be a port mismatch - if your AS400 is running on 8474 for sure? What is the exact value in your variable "server" in the Java file that works.

Comment: From what platform are you connecting to the AS400?

Comment: There is a Trace class within the JTOpen jar file.  Enable tracing and see what kind of output you get.

Comment: connection works on port 1521. thanks a lot to everyone! in the java file it was simply not specified, so it used the standard 1521 port i guess...

Comment: Database server on the IBM i is on port 8474 by default. http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/faq/ports.html  I don't know web logic, but if you got connected via 1521, then I'd say you're connecting to a local orcal servie that's then connecting to the IBM i.